# SSIS - Teradata Attunity Connector and SQLServer 2016

Tags: sql-server, ssis, teradata, dataflow, attunity

I have no problem running an SSIS package from VS2015 on my dev machine transferring from Teradata 15 to SQLServer 2016 using Attunity 4.0 and all of the following from TTU 16.10.01:

- ODBC Driver
- OLEDB Access Module
- .Net Data Provider
- TPT Base
- TPT Stream

  but when I deploy the package to the same SQLServer the execution fails with this error:

**"Data Flow Task:Error: The version of Teradata Source - [source name] is not compatible with this version of the DataFlow."**

I have installed exactly the same Attunity & TTU drivers on the server.

Have I missed setting up something on the SQL Server?

Comment: Still stuck with this issue. I have created a dev environment: Win 10 / VS2015 & SSDT / SQL Server 2016 sp1 / Attunity TD 4.0 & 5.0 (x86 & 64) / Teradata 15 TTU

I can create and successfully execute a package to pull data from TD to the SQL Server but when I deploy the package to the same SQL server it fails with "Data Flow Error: The version of Teradata Source is not compatible with this version of the DataFlow":

I suspect the issue might be having both v4.0 & v5.0 installed. But if I remove v5.0 I cannot create the package in VS 2015.

Answer (score 0):

SSIS Connectors v5.0 for Oracle and Teradata supports only TPT API versions : 14.10; 15; 15.10
You need to downgrade TTU to 15.10 or wait for Connector v6.0 release

Comment: Hi badun - thanks for this.
I do have TTU Base 15.10.05.00 installed
Any other ideas would be much appreciated!